# How to locate an element using Selenium by its visible text

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait, partiallinktext

I have this common situation where I want to locate an element by it's visible text, but the text is next to an i tag used for icons (not sure if this is valid HTML or not). It's the way a certain button component is set up that's used all over the site under test.

Here's some example HTML

```
<a href="#/provider_data_files/create" ng-click="providerDataFileCtrl.showAddProviderDataFileModal()" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
        <i class="fa fa-plus btn-icon"></i> 
        Add Provider Data File
</a>
```

For the moment, ignore all the other ways to locate this link, as my use case requires using the visible text. How can I locate this element by the visible text? The xpath:

```
//*[contains(text(), 'Add Provider Data File')]
```

fails, I assume because of the weird structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the html:

```
<a href="#/provider_data_files/create" ng-click="providerDataFileCtrl.showAddProviderDataFileModal()" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
    <i class="fa fa-plus btn-icon"></i> 
    Add Provider Data File
</a>
```

The desired `<a>` node consists of 2 child nodes:

- A *`<i>`* node
- A *Text* node with the text *`Add Provider Data File`*

---

### Solution

To locate the element by it's visible text i.e. ***Add Provider Data File*** you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Add Provider Data File")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(., 'Add Provider Data File')]")
  ```

To locate the ***visible*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Add Provider Data File")))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(., 'Add Provider Data File')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Proof of concept

[image: Add Provider Data File]

Comment: Wow what an awesome answer :) This is exactly what I needed. I appreciate the more general XPath solution as well for similar situations with non-anchor tags. It seems like the only difference in our XPath solutions is that you replace text() with the `.` operator. I'd be interested to know exactly what the text function does, may have to go down a rabbit hole :)

Comment: Feel free to discuss incase any queries in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.